# Allowing access to EMC and EMS remotely

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

What permissions changes do I need to make to allow an account to log into EMC or EMS from either another domain-joined server, or another PC?

I have installed the Exchange Management Tools from the installation media, however I don't appear to be able to log in either via the 'Add Exchange Forest' option in EMC, or via EMS.

Answer (score 0):

Per TechNet:

> To perform administrative tasks on a remote Exchange 2010 server, the account you use must be assigned the management roles that allow that feature to be managed. To determine the required management roles, see the Help topic for each feature. For more information about permissions, assigning management roles and management role scopes, and the rights required to administer Exchange 2010, see [Understanding Permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297943(v=exchg.141).aspx).

Do you want this account to be able to have the ability to perform all the administrative functions in Exchange?

Here is the list of Builtin Groups from the [Understanding Permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297943(v=exchg.141).aspx) page:

1. **Organization Management**
   Administrators who are members of the Organization Management role group have administrative access to the entire Exchange 2010 organization and can perform almost any task against any Exchange 2010 object, with some exceptions, such as the Discovery Management role.
2. **View-Only Organization Management**
   Administrators who are members of the View Only Organization Management role group can view the properties of any object in the Exchange organization.
3. **Recipient Management**
   Administrators who are members of the Recipient Management role group have administrative access to create or modify Exchange 2010 recipients within the Exchange 2010 organization.
4. **UM Management**
   Administrators who are members of the UM Management role group can manage features in the Exchange organization such as Unified Messaging (UM) server configuration, UM properties on mailboxes, UM prompts, and UM auto attendant configuration.
5. **Help Desk**
   The Help Desk role group, by default, enables members to view and modify the Microsoft Office Outlook Web App options of any user in the organization. These options might include modifying the user's display name, address, and phone number. They don't include options that aren't available in Outlook Web App options, such as modifying the size of a mailbox or configuring the mailbox database on which a mailbox is located.
6. **Hygiene Management**
   Administrators who are members of the Hygiene Management role group can configure the antivirus and anti-spam features of Exchange 2010. Third-party programs that integrate with Exchange 2010 can add service accounts to this role group to grant those programs access to the cmdlets required to retrieve and configure the Exchange configuration.
7. **Records Management**
   Users who are members of the Records Management role group can configure compliance features, such as retention policy tags, message classifications, and transport rules.
8. **Discovery Management**
   Administrators or users who are members of the Discovery Management role group can perform searches of mailboxes in the Exchange organization for data that meets specific criteria and can also configure legal holds on mailboxes. For more information, see Discovery and Understanding Litigation Hold.
9. **Public Folder Management**
   Administrators who are members of the Public Folder Management role group can manage public folders and databases on servers running Exchange 2010.
10. **Server Management**
    Administrators who are members of the Server Management role group can configure server-specific configuration of transport, Unified Messaging, client access, and mailbox features such as database copies, certificates, transport queues and Send connectors, virtual directories, and client access protocols.
11. **Delegated Setup**
    Administrators who are members of the Delegated Setup role group can deploy servers running Exchange 2010 that have been previously provisioned by a member of the Organization Management role group. For more information about delegated setup, see Provision Exchange 2010 Server and Delegate Setup.

Comment: Thanks for that. So by adding the user to any of those groups will at least allow the user to log into the EMC? Our admin account is a member of 'recipient management', but it's not letting us in. I'm thinking the problem might not be related to permissions after all..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update the EMC install on your client machine to the same version of Exchange you are connecting too. This will help with the connection problem. I needed to install Exchange SP3 to get mine working for version 14.03.

You will also need to add the user you are connecting as to the "Organization Management" group on the exchange server to enable more features, like creating new mailboxes.